# Changing selected option value does not change the DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs

There is a dropdown menu with `<select>` and some `<option>`-Tags in the source code.

If you manually change the option value by clicking - the content of a `<div>` with an id `#xyz` will be changed (by ajax, js ...)

Now I wrote a js-script and called it with CasperJS to simulate this. The script works fine and when I get the snapshot.png the select option is changed by:

```
$('select#zzz').val('123').change();
```

or

```
document.querySelector('select#zzz').selectedIndex = 2;
```

Then the script will wait a few seconds (5000ms).

But the div content will not be "refreshed" or "changed".

Does anyone know, why?

Here is the Script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    loadImages:false,
    verbose: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
    clientScripts: ["jquery.min.js"]
});

casper.start('http://www.somewebsite.tld', function() {
    this.test.assertExists('select[id="zzz"]', 'select is found');
});

this.evaluate( function() {
    document.querySelector('select#zzz').selectedIndex = 2;
    //$('select#zzz').val('123').change();
 });

casper.wait(5000, function() {  
    this.capture("screenshot.png");
    fs.write('results.json', this.getPageContent(), 'w'); 
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Dropdown selected').exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oldish question but you need to use

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
  $('select#zzz').val('123').change();
});
```

and not

```
this.evaluate( function() {
```